# How to add an Int to a generic Arraylist, I'm not sure if I'm insane or if it is impossible

Tags: java, generics

I was tasked to convert some code from using Int[] to using ArrayList. In doing so I am only allowed to edit these methods: Stack(int), getStack(), setStack(), stackRead(), and stackWrite(). When I do this I get a slew of errors regarding different type matches.

As stated before I can only edit Stack(int), getStack(), setStack(), stackRead(), and stackWrite().
In editing these I have come up with the code below:

My goal is to make this code to use ArrayList, but it creates many problems, I've tried changing everything relevant to a generic and parsing to an Int but it gives my out of bounds errors.

I have already tried changing getStack() to an object by using .toArray and it still gives me ArrayIndexOutofBounds

```
public class Stack<E> {    
     /**
     * This ArrayList stores the values on the Stack, i.e., it is *the stack*.
     */
    private ArrayList<E> mStack;

    /**
    /**
     * Default constructor. Creates a Stack with capacity of 10 ints.
     */
    public Stack() {
        this(10);
    }

    /**
     * This constructor creates a Stack with capacity of pCapacity. It initializes all three of
     * the data members.
     *
     * @param pCapacity - The capacity of the Stack.
     */
    public Stack(int pCapacity) {
        setCapacity(pCapacity);
        setStack(new ArrayList<E>(mCapacity));
        setTop(0);
    }

    private ArrayList<E> getStack() {
        return mStack; 
    }

    public int peek() {
        return (int)stackRead(getTop());
    }



    /**
     * Removes the top element from the Stack.
     *
     * @return The top value.
     */
    public int pop() {
        int topValue = peek();
        stackWrite(getTop(), 0);
        decTop();
        return topValue;
    }

    /**
     * Pushes pValue onto the top of the stack.
     *
     * @param pValue - The value to be pushed onto the top of the stack.
     *
     * @return A reference to the Stack. This permits operations such as:
     * myStack.push(1).push(2).push(3).push(4).
     */    
    public Stack push(int pValue) {
        stackWrite(incTop(), pValue);
        return this;     
    }4

    /**
     * Gets the value at index pIndex from the stack data structure and returns the value.
     *
     * @param pIndex the index into mStack where we are reading a value.
     * @return The value at pIndex.
     */
    private E stackRead(int pIndex) {
        return getStack().get(pIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Puts pValue into the stack data structure at index pIndex.
     *
     * @param pIndex The inex into mStack where we are writing pValue.
     * @param pValue The value to be writtin into mStack.
     *
     * @return pValue.
     */
    private int stackWrite(int pIndex, int pValue) {
        //getStack().set(pIndex,  pValue);

        return  pValue;
    }

}
```

Somehow the code needs to be written so that only the allowed methods are edited, while changing from 1d Arrays to generic ArrayLists

Comment: Seeing as `Stack` specifies a generic type `E`, use `E`, not `int`. Then, you can simply initialize a `Stack<Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store primitives like `int` in an `ArrayList`. Use the `Integer` class.